# "raw notes" VS "rough notes"

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering what's the right word to use when speaking about notes that are not polished: "rough notes" or "raw notes"?

Are both valid? Does one of them sound more "natural" or "native" than the other?

Comment: You could share *rough notes*.  You could speak from *raw notes* or *running notes* (e.g. from a meeting, phone call, or interview.  These would presumably be messy and you might be planning to neaten them up or put them in a better format later.  I do keep a running log of raw notes myself and if a question comes up months later I can go back and look at them.

Answer (score 1):

"Rough notes" is a fairly common term. I've never heard "raw notes."

Comment: Looks like there are some uses from legit english sources: https://ludwig.guru/s/raw+notes